# Get max value from alpha numeric column

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have an Excel sheet. In ID column, there are multiple IDs in column and contain one letter in start.

Now in cell `B1` and `B2`, I want to apply the [Max Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDdYh.png) which should get the maximum ID of `t` and `h` respectively.

The problem is when I Use `MAX(--RIGHT(B5:B11,3))`, it only returns maximum number. But I want to show the maximum ID of `t` and `h` in those cells.

Please help me on this. I need any non-VBA solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
B1: =MAX(IF(LEFT(B5:B11,1)="t",--RIGHT(B5:B11,3),0))
B2: =MAX(IF(LEFT(B5:B11,1)="h",--RIGHT(B5:B11,3),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that it's an array formula. So you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when leaving the formula bar.